# Present simple tense: general truth

Tags: present-simple

Present simple tense can be used for general truth. And “general truth” means “something true for most or all cases.

> Water freezes at 32 degrees Fahrenheit, 0 degrees Celsius.

Shouldn’t this sentence be in present simple form because water doesn’t always freeze?

Comment: This question is not about English.

Comment: @Jeffrey Carney Could you migrate the post where it should be please?

Comment: I do not have that privilege

Comment: @Jeffrey Carney Then, why don’t you teach me? :)

Comment: I don't understand this question.  It *is* a general truth that water freezes at 32 degrees.  The fact that water doesn't *always* freeze at 32 degrees is not important.  You said it yourself: "something true for **most** or all cases."

Comment: @stangdon Doesn’t general truth mean something always happens?

Comment: @stangdon I think I don’t know the meaning of “general.”

Comment: No, "general" does not mean "always".  If you look in the dictionary you will see definitions like "applicable to or characteristic of the majority of individuals involved" and "concerned or dealing with universal rather than particular aspects".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Water ***freezes*** IF the temperature drops to (at least) 32°F or 0 °C.

In order for water to freeze it must meet that condition.

> The sun ***rises*** in the east.

This is a fact and it is always true because *the sun never rises* in the south, west, or north.

Google break....

Oh no! The Internet tells me that *the sun only rises* in the east twice a year.

> [Most people know that the Sun "rises in the east and sets in the west"](http://solar-center.stanford.edu/AO/sunrise.html). **However, most people don't realize that is a generalization**. Actually, the Sun only rises due east and sets due west on 2 days of the year -- the spring and fall equinoxes! On other days, the Sun rises either north or south of "due east" and sets north or south of "due west."

Generally speaking, facts and basic truths are expressed in the present simple but not always, sometimes we can use "will" for things that always happen or for general characteristics, e.g.

> - [The sun will rise tomorrow.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem)
> - [Water will boil at 100°C](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/110605/1694)
> - It’s made of wool. [It’ll shrink if you wash it in hot water.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/will)